# I can not remove folder from server

Tags: permissions, directory, php

Accidentall I created the folder on remotely server (Server OS is Linux) using php: `mkdir("folder_name",0);`

Now I can not delete this folder from server. I think this is from permission, because `0` is not correct permission.

When I am trying delete this folder which php function `rmdir()`, php returns error

```
Unable to access on this folder.
```

Same error obtain I, when trying change access which php's `chmod()` function.

I can not delete folder which FTP client also.

So how can I delete this folder?

Comment: Is the directory empty? Who is owner of the directory? `ls -l directory` should give as enough information to proceed.

Comment: Do you have shell access to the server? And if so, do you have root access?

Comment: Are you sure that your folder is even created?

Comment: You created the directory with permission 0 (instead of something like 0755). Ask the admin to remove it.

Comment: ...and tell the admin to switch off `mkdir` and many other filesystem-operationgs for php. The directory structure should be in the hands of the operating system - not the application.

Comment: In *nix/BSD, we call them directories, not folders. That's a Windows-ism.

Answer (score 0):

Does running the below help?

```
system('rm -Rf some_dir');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

chmod("folder_name",0700);   // Read, write, execute for owner
rmdir("folder_name");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using shared hosting, you can change permissions on folders using a file manager provided by your control Panel.

For instance, in CPanel, you have a file manager that let you change the permissions for files and folders.

[image]